# Marking existing date string (from mysql) as UTC in javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm writing a new nodejs-based app which has to work with an existing (less-than-ideal) mysql database.

The database has a DATETIME column, storing values like `2015-08-21 18:12:06`. The original application always stored dates in UTC, but there's no valid timezone in the data itself.

This creates a problem when querying the data in a javascript environment because it assumes it's local time.

Querying the data using the node package `mysql`, the output of this date value has the wrong timezone:

```
Fri Aug 21 2015 18:12:06 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

I need a way to tell javascript that this is already in UTC. I can't change the original database structure because other/older apps use it.

Trying to use `.toUTCString()` automatically converts the string to UTC a second time, resulting in the wrong time:

```
Sat, 22 Aug 2015 01:12:06 GMT
```

All I can think of is manually parsing all dates and handling the conversion manually.

Comment: Did you notice the [`timezone`](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#connection-options) option?

Comment: I didn't realize, that seems to solve it!